# How to change the font of page numbers in TOC LOT LOF without "tocloft"?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, page-numbering

It can be easily done with `tocloft`, however, as there are already many settings for the whole document, using it caused the changing of spacing, and some conflicts with other packages, etc, compared to the original style for `book` class.

[image]

So how to change the font of page numbers for chapters, sections , tabs and figs.. in front matter, without use of `tocloft` package.

**Edit 1:**

Using `tocloft`

```
\usepackage[ ]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries \sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{ \sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{ \sffamily}  
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecpagefont}{ \sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{ \sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpagefont}{ \sffamily}
```

The error:

[image]

The following commands have been commented:

```
% \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}  
% \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

I dont know if `tocloft` is conflicted with `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`.

Besides, the spacing between entries in TOC, LOT, LOF are enlarged, and the blank pages are also removed which is created by default in `book` class.

Comment: It might help if you explain _why_ you can't use `tocloft`.

Answer (score 10):

The formatting of these lines is controlled by macros `\l@chapter` `\l@section` etc. In `book` class, `\l@chapter` has a custom definition but all the rest are defined in terms of `\@dottedcontentsline` so it is enough to redefine just those two commands to use a custom font. Here I use italic and colour to highlight the effect.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\let\oldl@chapter\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter#1#2{\oldl@chapter{#1}{\textcolor{red}{\itshape#2}}}

\let\old@dottedcontentsline\@dottedtocline
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\old@dottedcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{{\textcolor{green}{\itshape#5}}}}



\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{bbaa}

\section{zax}

aaa
\begin{figure}\caption{fff}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{ggg}\end{figure}


\section{xxzz}
bb
\chapter{bbaa}

\end{document}
```